# Extracting all records from a model and getting them to add them up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app with Order and Part models (an order has_many parts). I'm trying to put together a list of all outstanding parts but as different orders can have the same parts I need to remove duplicates while increasing the totals. I've tried a few ways but just can't get my head around it at the moment

Comment: Could you put what have you tried? It looks like standard has_and_belongs_to_many relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to make it as a `has_many :through` association.

The idea is to have 3 tables ex:

- Order
- Part
- OutstandingPart (example name)

OutstandingPart, this table holds the connection between orders and parts while having some additional details like outstanding_date etc

have a look at rails docs on the [**2.4 The has_many :through Association**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

some more links [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/what-is-a-has_many-through-association-in-ruby-on-rails-treehouse-quick-tip) and [here](https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/)

Comment: Sorry it's a late reply but this was really helpful, the app is moving along nicely :) It's good fun this coding jazz

Comment: @RobWilliams, glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use `:has_and_belongs_to_many` association. It uses a cross table between Orders and Parts, storing pairs of their ids. You may switch to `has_many :through` later using the same table.